# Eclipse issue with ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

Does anyone know how to repair/clean install eclipse?

My version of Eclipse Juno with the ADT plugin has been behaving very strangely, but since Eclipse runs straight away without installing, I don't know how to reconfigure it to its initial state.

I was working on an Android layout when I noticed that lines of xml layout code was disappearing as I typed. The code itself was not being deleted, it just wasn't displaying - sometimes I couldn't even see the code I was typing or it was looking as if it was overwriting something else.

And the final straw just happened now. Somehow, my keyboard got stuck on the Ctrl button via eclipse. So after I quit the program, my Ctrl button was still pressed in. So trying to type "s" in notepad was bringing up the Save dialog and when I opened Word, it asked me if I wanted to start in safe mode since the ctrl key was being pressed. The solution was to restart my laptop (this bug was still present when I plugged a keyboard in before restarting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps Ctrl getting stuck wasn't the final straw, but the whole problem?  This sort of thing happens to me fairly frequently (in Windows).  Control, Shift, Alt get stuck down causing confusing behaviour.  What's actually happening is that for some reason the key-up event is getting lost, so the OS thinks the key is still down.  It happens especially often if you're alt-tabbing into a VM, or using a hardware debugger (where the key up happens within the debug session).

The solution, whenever you think this is happening to you, is to just press all the modifier keys one at a time (left shift,right shift, alt, left control, right control etc) so the OS knows the state of them.  No need to reboot the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `eclipse -clean` from command line.

If that doesn't help try reinstalling the ADT plugin by first removing it from Help -> About -> Installation Details and then reinstalling following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html